# memtest86+ 5.31 fails to boot from USB

Tags: usb, memory, memtest86+

Older 5.01 bundled with modern Linux Distros does not seem to support modern memory (showed 192 bits for one module of DDRAM4 on my laptop, freezes shortly after testing starts) and looking at https://www.memtest.org/:

> ```
> Memtest86+ V5.31b (12/04/2020)
> Memtest86+ V5.01 (27/09/2013)
> ```

2013! But 5.31 dated 2020.

> -= Change Log =-
>
> Here is all the latest change logs for memtest86+ :
>
> Enhancements in v5.31b :
>
> After a long hiatus without updates and following numerous requests, I've started compiling many codes branches to release public
> builds again! Here is Memtest86+ 5.31b, with many bug fixes in the
> core functions. This build is not ready for production yet, because it
> lacks some feedbacks from beta-testers. Additional features and
> updated detection code will follow soon, as soon I have access to my
> lab with all the reference test platforms. It's currently inaccessible
> due to the COVID19 lockdown.
> If you find a bug or regression in this build, please send your feedback to memtest (-A-) memtest.org. Thank you!

I've downloaded 5.31, wrote iso file to USB and it does not boot (tried on two PCs). In readme:

> -e There is nothing to do here
> Memtest86+ is located on the bootsector of this CD
> -e Just boot from this CD and Memtest86+ will launch

Is it really only CD bootable? How to make it boot from USB? I've tried isohybrid on it but got: "unexpected boot catalogue parameters".

Comment: Did you tried Rufus with image of MemTest for USB?

Comment: @pbies, nope, I've used same app that I usually use to make liveUSB of Linux and they boot both UEFI and legacy. I'm ready to try app in you comment if somebody confirms 5.31 booted and provided Rufus version that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replace memtest86+ on liveUSB with newer 5.31. I've recently learned how to rebuild Linux distro iso, info if somebody interested are mostly in by following [QA on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675211/mkisofs-error-boot-image-efibot-img-not-an-allowable-size/679412#679412). and [that my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679365/446998).

5.31 have not frozen (at least not yet), but it does not display my LPDDR3 type correctly (only "DDR3-") and does not display frequency. Timings are displayed but as memory type is not correct, I wonder if timings are correct.